# breeze - adding new models from linked database on same server

Tags: .net, breeze

i have a big project in visual studio .net framework C# all set up already.  It uses breeze usually to pull much of the data and queries.  I see it's mostly done with just model classes (that look sort of like the tables fields) and mapping classes for those models.  I now need to add a new table to the model that is part of a linked database on the same server.  how would i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told to just create my own model and add it to the context.cs file and that's it.